# How to Moq a read only property which value depends on the the class method invoke?

Tags: c#, methods, interface, moq

I have an interface, something like this

```
public interface IContent 
{bool IsCheckedOut {get; };    
 void CheckOut(); 
}
```

The CheckOut() method affects the value the property IsCheckedOut returns.  For example, IsCheckedOut returns false until CheckOut() method is invoked. After that, the IsCheckedOut property returnse true.
I would like to test CheckOut method something like this

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckOutSetsCheckedOutStatusToTrue()
{
    var content  =  new Mock <IContent>();    

  // test mock CheckOut() method, something like this
   content.Setup(x => x.CheckOut()); 
   content.Object.CheckOut();

   // Verify 
    Assert.AreEqual(true, content.IsCheckedOut); //Test works as expected
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var isCheckedOut = false;
content.Setup(x => x.CheckOut()).Callback(() => { isCheckedOut = true; });
content.SetupGet(x => x.IsCheckedOut).Returns(() => isCheckedOut);
content.Object.CheckOut();
```

Answer (score 5):

A mock might not be the best approach, it's probably easier to write a stub object which implements the interface to give you the behavior you need:

```
public class CheckoutStub : IContent
{
    public bool IsCheckedOut { get; private set; }
    public void CheckOut() { IsCheckedOut = true; }
}
```

A mock is used to verify the behavior of the system under test, and perhaps you just need this for input.

However, you can create stubs with Moq, it is usually just more work:

```
var isCheckedOut = false;
content.Setup(x => x.CheckOut()).Callback(() => { isCheckedOut = true; });
content.SetupProperty(x => x.IsCheckedOut);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, c odekazein. I'll use stub idea in future.